# k8s config map how to apply

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

i've a question i create my config map but i dont know how to apply them to k8s ?
if i execute the command

```
kubectl get configmap configmap-cas-properties -o yaml
```

i can see my configmap. However i cant find any information on how to add it to k8s .

I going to use it with my pod where i already set

```
 envFrom:
       - configMapRef:
           name: configmap-cas-app-properties
           name: configmap-cas-properties    restartPolicy: never
```

Answer (score 2):

The ConfigMaps can be set as Environment variables which can be read in the application. Another way is to mount the ConfigMaps as a Volume in the Container and the application read the data from there. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) is the documentation from K8S on the same.

Comment: but how can i apply the configmap to kubernets after running the command kubectl create configmap ?

Comment: The documentation explains clearly on how to use it.